# A prime in a Galois extension of degree p either totally splits or is inert

Tags: class-field-theory

I'm reading *class field theory* by Neukirch, and i have a question seems simple but I can't find an answer by myself.

Now L/K is a cyclic Galois extension of number fields of degree p, and p is a prime number. In the page 130 of this book, it says that a prime of K that is not inert splits completely, i.e., decomposes into exactly p primes of L. But a prime of K which is not inert can be totally ramified, i.e., the index of ramification e=p, I don't know why this case hasn't been considered.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As I happen to have that book, I looked it up. I'm afraid I never made it that far in the book. I was expecting an umbrella statement excluding the ramifified primes, but there is none. The set $S$ of primes is explicitly required to contain all the ramified primes. But whatever I once learned of Herbrand quotients and such has been thoroughly erased by the teeth of time. Can't help you, sorry.  Knowledgable people (like F. Lemmermeyer, one of the translators) do show up here, so let's wait :-)

Comment: I think you can just replace “inert” in the definition of $n_1$ (and the following paragraphs) with “non-split” (ie inert or totally ramified), the reasoning (as far as I can tell) works.